# Two webapps with different Spring versions in one container feasible and practical?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the task of migrating our webapp from grand old Spring 2.X (mvc, security, webflow etc.) to Spring 3.X, which is quite some work but actually pretty straight-forward. Now I ran into a few problems regarding our closed-source, commercial piece of community-functionality, which apparently is built against Spring 2.X. I tried decompiling parts of it, recompiling with updated Spring packages etc., but it's very cumbersome and after a day of work I stopped since this does not seem to be the right direction I'm headin.

Is it possible to strip apart those parts of the whole webapp alongside the commercial stuff (which unfortunately cannot be exchanged just like that, it'd be a rather large project) and weave a new 'legacy'-webapp that's running Spring 2.X, while having the larger part migrated to Spring 3.X - and everything up and running in the same container, hopping to and fro?

so e.g. when accessing URLs like /account/overview.htm the legacy-webapp is accessed while the rest is being served from the brand-new one??

If this sounds like too far ahead, I'm open for alternatives....

thanks beforehand!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is both YES/NO:

- of course you can run two different war in the same container regardless of the libraries they use
- you must be aware of the two webapps holding two different contexts (beans, authentication, ...)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the different contexts! this could be some sort of problem but maybe not... thx